# Deleting Last Row of Table / Prevent Header Deletion

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have the following code which is assigned to a button.  When pressed, the button will delete the last row in a table.  The table's top row is a header.  I'm trying to figure out how to prevent/protect the header (B6:M6) and the rows above it from being deleted accidentally if the "delete row" button is clicked one too many times.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

Dim LastRow As Integer

          LastRow = Worksheets("MTO").Range("J" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
          Worksheets("MTO").Rows(LastRow & ":" & LastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Also if your File is dynamic/big, I would put LastRow as Long instead of Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `If` statement to check the value of LastRow before you delete it. (Also, you will want to fully qualify your objects using the Sheet)

```
Sub DeleteRow()
      Dim LastRow As Long
      LastRow = Worksheets("MTO").Range("J" & Worksheets("MTO").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
      If LastRow > 6 Then
          Worksheets("MTO").Rows(LastRow & ":" & LastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
      End If
End Sub
```

[If Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Or simplify it using a `With`

```
Sub DeleteRow()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  With Worksheets("MTO")
      LastRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
      If LastRow > 6 Then
          .Rows(LastRow & ":" & LastRow).Delete shift:=xlUp
      End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `LastRow > 6` Mark's header ends at `B6:M6`

Comment: @R.Roe Yup - Good catch.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to declare worksheet variable to make the code more readable.

You may try something like this...

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set ws = Worksheets("MTO")
    LastRow = ws.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow > 6 Then ws.Rows(LastRow).Delete
End Sub
```